# docker clone an existing elasticsearch container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

So currently, I have an existing container that's running Elasticsearch in one server. What I want to do is to clone the container (including the existing data) and put it inside another server.

Is this possible? I'm still new to Docker and I'm getting confused if [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/thaJeztah/8d0e901bd21329d80cf2) is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The Elasticsearch documentation has some [setup instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/docker.html), and in particular an admonition to [always bind data volumes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/docker.html#_always_bind_data_volumes).  Hopefully you've done that already.

The important detail here (and this is common across Docker) is that the container itself is irrelevant, so long as we can preserve the underlying data.  We want to move the data to the other system, and then we can start a new container based on that data.

If you're using Docker [named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for the Elasticsearch storage, then you need to go through the procedure in the Docker documentation to [back up and restore data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).  If you're using Docker Compose to launch Elasticsearch, you can use [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) to run the backup command:

```sh
docker-compose run -v $PWD:/export -w /usr/share/elasticsearch/data es01 \
  tar cvzf /export/es01.tar.gz .
scp docker-compose.yml es01.tar.gz there:
ssh there

docker-compose run -v $PWD:/export -w /usr/share/elasticsearch/data es01 \
  tar xvzf /export/es01.tar.gz
docker-compose up -d
```

If you've chosen a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) instead, it's enough to just `scp -r` the data directory from your host to the other system.

The gist you link to advocates `docker commit`.  That's almost never a best practice, since it creates one-off images that you can't reproduce later.  (If you later need to upgrade Elasticsearch, you're not going to spin up the old server, start ES, and commit it again.)  In this particular context, the `elasticsearch` image is configured to always store its data in a volume (an anonymous volume if none is otherwise specified) and neither `docker commit` nor `docker build` will preserve volume contents.

Also in the specific context of Elasticsearch, if you can configure the old and new nodes to join together into a cluster, you can let ES's ordinary replication handle this.  (Start the new node, make sure all indexes have at least two replicas configured, wait for the cluster to be green, and terminate the old node.)  If you don't already have this set up, though, just cloning the data volume as discussed above will be much easier.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but I checked the container and it's not using volumes at all. I managed to make a backup of the data in /usr/share/elasticsearch/data, should I just copy that into the new container instead?

Comment: Yes.  (And make sure to mount a volume of some sort there, or else you're likely to lose data as soon as you need to restart the container.)

Comment: I managed to copy the backed-up data into the new container, but there's an error about failing to obtain node locks.